# Replace string in a function at runtime Android NDK

Tags: android, c++, c, android-ndk

I have an external compiled static C++ library that I'm using in my android application. This library is reading a file. I want to know if there is a way I can "redirect" the function that's reading the file so that it reads another file.

So if it does:

```
fopen("myfile.txt", "rb");
```

I want to intercept it and to do this instead:

```
fopen("myotherfile.txt", "rb");
```

In Objective-C I use [MethodSwizzling](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?MethodSwizzling). Is there something similar I can do in C++ or the android NDK?

Comment: can you not pass the string into the library?

Comment: If the library is static, maybe you can use objcopy or something like that to remove the string literal and provide your own version of the literal instead...

Comment: @slayton no the library doesn't provide a way to pass the string into the library (it forces you to place a file in a certain directory). -Kerrek SB Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @Tayeb, can you use a symbolic link?  Place the link where the file is supposed to be and then have it point to your desired file.

Comment: try to rename the file to myfile.txt and then rename it back once your done :D

Comment: @slayton I've dont a bit of digging around the internet about using symbolic links, do you have any idea how it can be used in an android application?

Comment: @bob thanks, the problem is it's not just the file name, but the directory location needs to be changed as well.

Comment: @Tayeb, creating a symbolic link is really easy in linux.  However they will only work on the device memory and not in the SD card as FAT and FAT32 don't support them.

Comment: @Tayeb, Personally I would what Bob suggested. Trying to edit the compiled library will be many more times difficult and prone to problems then renaming, copying, or moving around files.

Comment: as far as symlinks go, http://superuser.com/questions/216332/is-there-anything-like-a-link-or-shared-mount-point-for-fat32-folders-in-linux-an and also http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4044/is-possible-to-make-symbolic-links-in-the-android-filesystem-and-how I guess on a rooted phone and using the terminal editor it is possible for the internal filesystem

Answer (score 0):

Short of editing the binary (with uncertain results), your best option is to use a symlink... if you're just doing it for development purposes, you could use adb shell into your test device to create the symlink.

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html#issuingcommands

Answer (score 0):

How about contact the author of the library and ask them to introduce a parameter? Having hard-coded file paths is a lousy design anyway, the library will be better off.